# Not able to deploy solana smart contract over devnet

Tags: deployment, smartcontracts, solana

I have followed below steps to deploy my smart contract over solana devnet but i am facing Blockhashed Expired: 5 retries remaining .

I have followed below steps to deploy my smart contract over solana devnet but i am facing Blockhashed Expired: 5 retries remaining .

1. solana-keygen new --outfile solana/my_wallet.json --force
2. solana config set --url devnet
3. solana airdrop 2 0xxx .... 0xxxx [and get sufficient balance upto 10 sol]
4. anchor build
5. solana address -k target/deploy/my-keypair.json
6. Copy programId and updated my Anchor.toml file as well as Lib.rs file [declare_id]
7. Set cluster and programs to devnet in Anchor.toml file
8. anchor build
9. I updated programId in idl file as well.
10. anchor deploy --provider.cluster devnet

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: The issue has been resolved , there is a problem with the version we upgraded all dependencies and deployed.

Answer (score 0):

- this might be one issue

  solana address -k target/deploy/my-keypair.json

file name should include your contract name. this is the syntax

```
yourContractName-keypair.json
```

- you should also add this to `anchor.toml`

  ```
  cluster = "devnet"
  wallet = "./my_wallet.json"
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the Public RPC. One possible cause of this issue is that the public devnet RPC is overloaded.

You might want to try a private RPC. You can try using a service like [Quicknode](https://www.quicknode.com?tap_a=67226-09396e&tap_s=3509098-eddc20&utm_source=affiliate&utm_campaign=generic&utm_content=affiliate_landing_page&utm_medium=generic), which has private Solana devnet RPCs and a free tier you can use for this purpose.

Then, once you have the URL to your private node, you use:

`solana config set --url https://quicknode.com.....{insertrestofurl}`